# when concurrent threads fill a form in different browser windows, only one form is filled (and not completely either)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

First off, I only recently got acquainted Selenium/WebDriver/Maven/TestNG. Here's the situation:

- I need to test a webapp. The first page has a form to be filled; subsequent pages have various other actions.
- I have a class (say `App.java` )that automates most of the webapp using Selenium WebDriver.

  - Learning from the Selenium docs, I had [Maven create my project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project) and [import it into eclipse](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_java_driver_Sel20_via_maven.jsp#importing-maven-into-eclipse-reference).
- I now need to execute some test-cases in N parallel threads; which will call various methods from the earlier class. (based on the testcase)
- For this, I used Selenium Grid/Maven/TestNG using tips gleaned [from this link.](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2013/07/how-to-run-parallel-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-and-testng-2/) (and of course, Grid and TestNG documentation.)
- After setting everything up, I had the following architecture:

  - an `App.java` (and helper classes) that does the legwork of navigating each page of the webapp;
  - an `AppTest.java` (and `Test01...N.java`) that has testcases which call various methods in App.java.

Here's AppTest.java:

```
public class AppTest {
    protected ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> threadDriver = null;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc));
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return threadDriver.get();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeBrowser() {
        getDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

Here's Test01.java

```
public class TestGroup01 extends AppTest {
    //Doc wasnt clear, but with the values below, I got this testcase to be called 3 times in parallel
    @Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 3,  timeOut = 10000)     
    public void TestCase1() throws Exception {
            App.doSomething(getDriver());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

And here's `App.doSomething`

```
  public static WebDriver driver;
  public class App {
  public static void doSomething(WebDriver drv) throws Exception {
    driver = drv; //I did this to avoid having to pass drv to every method
    drv.get(URL_TO_TEST);
    AppHelper.enterData(); // this method now accesses driver
  }
  }
```

**Problem**

- The testcase opens up 3 browser windows (as expected). The URL gets loaded and the form opens (as expected). But only one of those windows has any data entered into it. And in that window, only one field is filled. I am completely unable to figure out why this is happening.
- The `App.doSomething` method is setting a static variable `driver` to avoid having to pass drv to every method. Is this somehow a cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was due to the `timeout` parameter passed to the `@Test` annotation.

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 3,  timeOut = 10000)
```

The parameter determines the maximum time that a test can run. Since I had set it to 10000ms, the test was being silently aborted after that time.